# Misprint in Fearless Symmetry by Ash and Gross? Conditions for Elliptic Curves.

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves

On page 104 of the paperback edition of *Fearless Symmetry* by Avner Ash and Robert Gross, they give one way of thinking of elliptic curves as $y^2=x^3+Ax+B$ wherein $A$ and $B$ can be any fixed integers so long as $2(4A^3+27B^2)\neq0$. Later, when discussing the example $y^2=x^3+1$, (so, an example wherein $A=0$ and $B=1$), they talk about how the above restrics the choices of number system $R$ we can make when looking for solution sets $E(R)$. It's probably best if I just quote directly (from the following p. 105):

"However, when we plug a number system $R$ into $E$ to get $E(R)$, we are tacitly assuming that $2(4A^3+27B^2)\neq0$ in $R$. So in our example we must assume that $6\neq0$ in $R$, so for instance $R=\mathbb F_2$ or $R=\mathbb F_3$ are not allowed for this $E$."

For the life of me, I can't imagine where the $6$ in that quote comes from. Obviously $54$—the actual calculation of the restriction—is a multiple of $6$, but I haven't seen any indications that that should matter, and I *think* there are situations in which the distinction might make a difference. For example—although I'll fully admit that I don't totally understand fields of the $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ format—I'm fairly certain that $6\neq0$ in $\mathbb F_{27}$, which, according to the quoted passage, would make $E(\mathbb F_{27})$ a valid answer set. However, I think that $54=0$ in $\mathbb F_{27}$, which would make $E(\mathbb F_{27})$ *invalid*.

What am I missing?

Comment: The prime field $\Bbb{F}_3$ is a subset of $R=\Bbb{F}_{27}$. When calculating $3=1+1+1$ we never leave that subset. So given that $3=0$ in $\Bbb{F}_3$ the same holds true in $R$.

Comment: A common way of constructing $R=\Bbb{F}_{27}$ is to think of it as
$$R=\{a_0+a_1\alpha+a_2\alpha^2\mid a_0,a_1,a_2\in\Bbb{F}_3\},$$ where $\alpha$ is a zero of a carefully chosen cubic polynomial (that must be irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_3$). That polynomial then tells us what $\alpha^3$ must be and the rest of the arithmetic of the field follows from that. My favorite cubic for this purpose would be $p(x)=x^3-x-1$. Whence
$$\alpha^3-\alpha-1=0\implies \alpha^3=\alpha+1.$$

Comment: If this feels a bit much at first, compare this to the construction of complex numbers
$$\Bbb{C}=\{a_0+a_1i\mid a_0,a_1\in\Bbb{R}\},$$ where that mysterious element $i$ is a zero of a quadratic polynomial $p(x)=x^2+1$ implying that $i^2+1=0$, or $i^2=-1$. Over $\Bbb{R}$ the only irreducible polynomials are linear and quadratic, so we can never go higher than 2-dimensional over $\Bbb{R}$. In sharp contrast to $\Bbb{F}_p$ where we have irreducible polynomials of any degree, and can construct $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ for all positive integers $n$.

Comment: Covering this all in a course on abstract algebra is a few weeks worth of material. I'm not sure it is prudent to try and answer it here as there are many details to worry about (such as using Euclid's algorithm on polynomials to show that all the non-zero elements in the resulting number systems have inverses. You may want to check this in the small case of
$$\Bbb{F}_9=\{a_0+a_1i\mid a_0,a_1\in\Bbb{F}_3\}.$$ There (everything done modulo three)
$$(1+i)(1-i)=2=-1$$ implying that
$$\frac1{1+i}=-(1-i)=-1+i=2+i.$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen This is phenomenal, thank you. I have a much better understanding of these kinds of fields already from your comments, and now I have a clearer path for exploring them. So, given these facts, do you think the quote in my question just changed 54 to 6 because that suffices to cover all possible cases?

Comment: Yes. Six is divisible by the same set of primes as $54$. They might have formulated it to read *$R$ should be a ring where $2$ and $3$ are invertible*. Elliptic curve people often exclude characteristics two and three (for in those cases you won't get the short Weierstrass form), and using six as a guinea pig is a way of covering both problematic cases at once. There may be other reason, but I would need to look at the source.